# Google Cloud Analytics Data API response only returns two results when there should be many

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics-api

When running the code below I only get the results shown below.  The Google analytics account shows more data.  Why am I not getting all data in response?

```
$my_ranges = [new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange(['start_date' => '2019-02-01', 
                                                           'end_date' => 'yesterday'
                                                          ])
             ];   
                                  
                                  
                                  
$my_dimensions = [new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension(['name' => 'browser',
                                                               'name' => 'landingPage',
                                                               'name' => 'newVsReturning',
                                                               'name' => 'pageReferrer',
                                                               'name' => 'pageTitle'
                                                              ])
                 ];
                                  
$my_metrics = [new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric(['name' => 'activeUsers',
                                                         'name' => 'newUsers',
                                                         'name' => 'sessions'
                                                        ])
              ]; 
                
                
                
$my_orderby = [new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy(['desc'  => true,
                                                          'metric' => new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy\MetricOrderBy(['metric_name' => 'sessions'])
                                                         ])
              ];
                                  
//broken google expect integer bug               
//$my_metric_agg = [new \Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\MetricAggregation(["TOTAL"])];                
                
                
                
                
       
                           
                           
$response = $client->runReport([
                                'property'           =>    'properties/'.$propertyID,
                                'dateRanges'         =>    $my_ranges,
                                'dimensions'         =>    $my_dimensions,
                                'metrics'            =>    $my_metrics,
                                'orderBy'            =>    $my_orderby,
                                'limit'              =>    10
                              ]);  
                              
                              //broken google bug so removed 
                              //'metricAggregations' =>    $my_metric_agg,
                           
                           
                           
foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) 
{
    foreach ($row->getDimensionValues() as $dimensionValue) 
    {
        echo 'Dimension Value: ' . $dimensionValue->getValue();
        
        echo "<br>";
        
    }
    
    foreach($row->getMetricValues() as $metricValue) 
    {
        
        echo 'Metric Value: ' . $metricValue->getValue();
        
         echo "<br>";
    }
    
}//close foreach response
```

And response is: (General Information is the page name), I dont know what Metric value is.

> Dimension Value: General Information
> Metric Value: 3

Comment: becouse your not running the same report on the web app as you are when you request the data via the api the request must be the same.

Comment: Ok thanks,  the analytics web page url and decoded it and tried to use this as an example of the json code.  analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/PROPERTY ID HERE/reports/dashboard?
params=_u..nav=maui
&_u..comparisons=[{" name":"Browser includes Chrome","isEnabled":true," 
                           filters":[{" fieldName":"browser","expressionList":["Chrome"], "isCaseSensitive":true
                   }]
        }]
&_r.. dimension-value={" dimension":"eventName","value":"page_view"}
&r=events-overview-page-view
&collectionId=business-objectives .  Is that the wrong approach?

Comment: Google Analyitics should have a feature where you push a button and it gives you the json code for the report you are viewing.  :)

Comment: Thats not a half bad idea I will bring it up with the team I have a meeting with them in a few weeks.    okay it was so good i just emailed them about it.